# How do I get an DataTable from IDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, idbcommand

I'm trying to get a `DataTable` or `DataSet` from an `IDataReader`, but I'm failing. Here's the code:

```
string sql = @"SELECT ID, DOCNUMBER FROM TBDOCUMENT";

using (IDbConnection conn = CreateConnection(provider, connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = sql;
                        IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        using (reader)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                long key = reader.GetInt64(0);
                                decimal value = reader.GetDecimal(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I'm using `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` because it will works with three different databases (the method `CreateConnection(provider, connectionString)` gets the specific type of connection according to the database).
My query gets an ID (as Int64) and a DocNumber (as Decimal), but every time I try to get the decimal value, it throws an `OverflowException` with a message: "Conversion overflows." Both of values are important to me, but I don't know how do I get these values.

Actually, the code I'm not trying to convert to a `DataTable`, I have to get the value of the two without exception.

Some help?

Comment: what is the column type of DOCNUMBER in the TBDOCUMENT table? if it's an integer you should have int value = reader.GetInt...

Comment: Hi Davide, the type of DOCNUMBER in TBDOCUMENT is Decimal(30,0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I haven't check by executing but it should work...

```
    // Load the data into the existing DataSet. 
    DataTableReader reader = GetReader();
    dataSet.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,
    customerTable, productTable); 

    // Load the data into the DataTable.
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
```

Comment: I believe that it should work. I tryed to execute here and throws an exception (OverflowException). Maybe the decimal values can't convert and then throws the exception.